# Add delay on mouseleave on dropdown menu

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu, opencart, delay, mouseleave

I'm using an older version of Opencart (1.5.5.1) and Journal theme.

The dropdown menu disappears immediately on mouseleave. This is not really a problem on desktop, but on touch screen devices it causes problems. I need it to stay a few seconds before preferably fading out quickly.

I have read a few similar posts about this subject, but find the solutions a bit difficult to apply to my code. I am not even sure if mouseleave applies to touch screens in the same way (probably not).

Can anyone please help by adding some sort of delay that works on both desktop and mobile?

Here's the code:

```
$('#cart > .heading a').die('click');
$('#cart').die('mouseleave').die('mouseover').die('mouseleave').die('click');
$('#cart').live('mouseover', function () {
    if (!$("#cart").hasClass('active')) {
        if (!Journal.isOC2) {
            $('#cart').load('index.php?route=module/cart #cart > *');
        }
        $('#cart').addClass('active');
        $('#cart').live('mouseleave', function () {
            $(this).removeClass('active');
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use jQuery [delay()](https://api.jquery.com/delay/) function. *"Only if you are using a jquery's function"*

But if you're going to remove the class by using `removeClass()` function it will not work. You can do something like this in CSS to delay some actions.

I use `transition-delay`. I hope this will exactly or atleast become close to your goal. :)

`

```js
$('#test').hover(function(){
  $('#dropdown').addClass('active');
}, function(){
  $('#dropdown').removeClass('active');
});
```

```css
/* Change transition-delay 2s(2 seconds) to how long do you want to delay it. */
#dropdown.active{
  opacity: 1 !important;  
  -webkit-transition-property: opacity; /* Safari */
    -webkit-transition-delay: 0s; /* Safari */
    transition-property: opacity;
    transition-delay: 0s;
}

#dropdown{
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition-property: opacity; /* Safari */
    -webkit-transition-delay: 2s; /* Safari */
    transition-property: opacity;
    transition-delay: 2s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="test">
    HOVER ME PLEASE!
</div>

<div id="dropdown">
    EXAMPLE DROPDOWN
</div>
```

`

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

You are probably right, but I cannot get this to work. Am I missing something?

Comment: Did you include your jquery script? I mean the jquery library.

Comment: Yes, this is running on a content management system, so I'm pretty sure all libraries are included within every page. In fact, this messy page is including at least 8 different jquery libraries.

Comment: @AlexanderAdam I found out that `delay()` function only works on functions such as `fadeIn()` not on `removeClass()` or `addClass()` so I think of using just CSS transition. I updated my answer above. Please check.

Comment: @AlexanderAdam I updated my answer again. I think I already did what you want with the help of CSS `transition-delay`. Please check it out if this is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the 
[setTimeout](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp)
function

You could even make it fade out first by using jQuery's fadeOut() function.

```
$(this).fadeOut(2000);
setTimeout(function(){
    $(this).removeClass('active');
}, 2000);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, ikdekker!

I've tried your solution and this certainly does something, but it does not seem to work because now the menu doesn't even close no matter how long I wait after moving the mouse.

Comment: Have you tried to see the timeout is triggered at all? (with a console.log() or alert()). By the way, I initially failed with my post and accidently put the parameters in the wrong order. Is your code exactly as my answer is now? If so, does the $(this) element target the right one?

Comment: Is the element you want to remove the class 'active' the one with id 'cart'? If not, replace $(this) with the desired class

Comment: I must have tried your first solution with the errors, because now it's working - except, it doesn't simply remove the dropdown, it removes the entire element including the parent. See this gif:
http://cdn.makeagif.com/media/3-22-2016/nZHfAZ.gif

I should probably note that the element needs to change from class="active" to class="" instead of display:none.

Not sure if this is relevant to the setTimeout function?

Comment: The removal of the active class is not relevant to the timeout function. The only thing you have to change is the fadeout, you should use $(this).find(CLASSOFUNDERLYINGDIV).fadeOut(2000). This is because the fadeOut hides the div and this holds the cart element, while you probably only want to hide the child

Comment: This does it:

    $(this).find('.content').fadeOut(2000)
     setTimeout(function(){
      $(this).removeClass('active');
    });

But now, after the child/dropdown is hidden, it won't return on mouse hover because it is set to display:hidden.

Comment: Yes ;) so you should add hover event on the cart with a i.e. $(this).(.content).show()

Comment: That makes sense, but I cannot figure out exactly where I need to place this bit. Would you mind please giving me a push in the right direction? :)

Comment: $( "#cart" ).mouseover(function() {

// in here 

});